# Cómo puedo hacer el login con los campos DNI(identificación) y password en MVC ASP.NET identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Cómo puedo hacer el login con los campos DNI(identificación) y password en MVC ASP.NET Identity, ya que el login por defecto está con el correo y la contraseña.
De antemano agradezco la colaboración ya que soy nuevo en este tema.

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, te recomiendo ir por https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour y https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask para que veas el funcionamiento del sitio y puedas mejorar la calidad de preguntas, por otro lado ¿Qué has intentado? Si recién estás iniciando con ASP.net MVC, dale play a https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY Espero te sea de utilidad :D

Comment: Inicialmente agregue la propiedad al  ApplicationUser, luego cambie la propiedad en el accountViewModel(RegisterViewModel y LoginViewModel ), pero siempre me genera un error, ya que no le estoy enviando el Email

Comment: estas trabajando con vs2015?

Comment: si, con VS 2015 C#